# Prove the following equalities about matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Let $A, B \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ two matrices such that $(A-B)^2=O_2$.
>   Prove:
>
> 1) $\det(A^2-B^2)=(\det(A) - \det(B))^2$
>
> 2) $\det(AB-BA)=0$ iff $\det(A)=\det(B)$

---

**My attempt**

Using Cayley it follows $\det(A-B)=0$ and $tr(A-B)=0$ therefore $tr(A)=tr(B)=t$ and $A^2 = tA-\det(A)I_2, B^2 = tB-\det(B)I_2$.

From the last two equalities: $A^2-B^2=t(A-B) - (\det(A) - \det(B))I_2$

Here I've got stuck, because applying determinant to the last equality doesn't seem to lead somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We have $A^2 - B^2 = t(A - B) + (\det(A) - \det(B))I$, and the eigenvalues of $A^2 - B^2$ are both $0$.  So, the eigenvalues of $A^2 - B^2$ are both $-(\det(A) - \det(B))$.  The product of these eigenvalues is
$$
\det(A^2 - B^2) = (\det(A) - \det(B))^2
$$
as desired.

Comment: I am sorry but could you explain your first relationship: In particular, what is $t$ ? A common value of the trace (but why should it be the same ?)?. Is this relationship coming from the subtraction of separate relationships $A^2= tA+ \det(A)I$ and  $B^2 = tB+\det(B))I$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie as in the question, $t = \operatorname{tr}(A)$. The trace values are the same since $\operatorname{tr}(A-B) = 0$, which is true since $(A - B)$ is nilpotent.

Comment: I understand now that your answer is perfectly understandable as a continuation of the attempts of the OP.

Comment: @JeanMarie I probably should have clarified that, in retrospect.